# Powershell Check if an XML attribute exists

Tags: powershell

Some XML files I'm looking at don't always include the name but

```
</NAME>
```

If I have trim() in the code it fails

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
   Title = $customer.Name.Title.Trim()
   FirstName = $customer.Name.First_Name.Trim()
   LastName = $customer.Name.Last_Name.Trim()
   EmailConsent = $emailConsent
   EmailSoftOptIn = $emailSoftOptIn
}
```

How can I check so not apply trim() when attribute isn't there.
I'm just researching to to see if I can assign to a variable and then check if it's empty but is this the best way.

This is linked to a previous post which was answered perfectly (I have put here for insight to full code)

[Powershell access XML node with multiple attributes within a forloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384957/powershell-access-xml-node-with-multiple-attributes-within-a-forloop/64386615?noredirect=1#comment113855130_64386615)

Comment: then check for null first

Comment: `$customer.Name.Title -as [string] |% Trim`

Comment: Thanks Mathias I was looking into using null as marsze suggested but that one above looks cleaner than my attempt

Comment: $Title = $customer.Name.Title
if($Title -ne $null) {$Title=$Title.Trim()}

Comment: Or use `('' + $customer.Name.Title).Trim()` or regex: `$customer.Name.Title -replace '^\s+|\s+$'`